# Django and format_html, getting duplicate text formatted and unformatted

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

I'm using Django 3 for a simple Book loan app. I'm trying to format the text (change color) using format_html but I get strange results.

I've the following class declaration:

```
class Prestamos(models.Model):
    estado_prestamo = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Estado', choices=STATUS_CHOICES)


    STATUS_CHOICES = (
      ('a', format_html('<font color="green">Activo</font>')),
      ('b', "Archivado"),
      ('w', format_html('<font color="red"><b>Vencido</b></font>')),
    )
```

This is the result in Filter Panel where I get duplicate text, formatted and unformatted.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

PD: Here is the ModelAdmin declaration (thanks Iain):

```
class PrestamosAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nombre_prestamo', 'correo_prestamo', 'fecha_alta', 'duracion', 'Material_en_préstamo', 'estado_prestamo', 'Ver_mat',)
    search_fields = ('numero_prestamo','nombre_prestamo', 'correo_prestamo', 
     'fecha_alta', 'duracion', 'material__num_com')
    list_filter = ('estado_prestamo', 'fecha_alta', 'fecha_baja')
    actions = ['archivar_prestamo','ImprimirPrestamo']
```

Comment: Can you share your ModelAdmin where you have added the filter?

Comment: Thank Iain, I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, by trial and error I found that removing the quotes in the html color declaration make it works.

Before

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
      ('a', format_html('<font color="green">Activo</font>')),
      ('b', "Archivado"),
      ('w', format_html('<font color="red"><b>Vencido</b></font>')),
    )
```

UPDATED, thanks to Iain.

After removing the quotes and replaced the `<font>` for `<span>` tags (html 5 support) :

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('a', format_html('<span style=color:green>Activo</span>')),
    ('b', "Archivado"),
    ('w', format_html('<b><span style=color:red>Vencido</span></b>')),
)
```

It works

[image]

Comment: I don't think `font` tags are valid in HTML5, some browsers may support them for backwards compatibility, maybe try using `span` tags instead?